# trying to understand this nested query, maybe it is a typo, also different way using having

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by, having

This is the database:

```
EMPLOYEE (fmane, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno)     KEY: ssn
DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)               KEY: dnumber.
PROJECT  (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum)                          KEY: pnumber.
WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours)                                         KEY: (essn, pno)
DEPENDENT  (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship)             KEY: (essn, dependent-name)
```

The question is:

> List ssn, last and first name of all the employees who is working on project number 02 using nested query

The answer that got right was:

```
select e.ssn, e.lname, e.fname
From employee e

where eissn in (select w.essn
                from works_on w
                 where w.essn = e.ssn and w.pno ='02'
               );
```

1) what is `eissn`? a typo, how would fix this?

2) is there another way writing the write answer, like using having or group on?

Comment: `eissn` seems to be a typo. It should probably be `e.ssn`. Adding redundant `i`s is a common typo while using [tag:vi] or [tag:vim], when you attempt to switch to insert mode, although you're already in it.

Comment: can you please write an answer and I promise I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eissn` is obviously a typo, as there is no such column. By examining the column list in the `employee` table I'm guessing it's supposed to be `e.ssn`. This would be especially plausible if whoever wrote the query used [vi](/questions/tagged/vi) or [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), where pressing `i` should switch you to insert mode, but would just add an `i` character if you're already in it.

Even after fixing the typo, though, this query needs some work. Specifically the `w.essn = e.ssn` is wrong for an `in` condition. You could either use an `in` condition without it:

```
SELECT e.ssn, e.lname, e.fname
FROM   employee e
WHERE  e.ssn IN (SELECT w.essn
                 FROM   works_on w
                 WHERE  w.pno ='02'
                );
```

Or convert the condition to an `exists` condition:

```
SELECT e.ssn, e.lname, e.fname
FROM   employee e
WHERE  e.ssn EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM   works_on w
                     WHERE  e.ssn = w.essn AND w.pno ='02'
                    );
```

Comment: also just one last thing select w.essn , is that select work on. why are works and pno used? I thought w.pno = 02 should be enough to give what you need. why select w.essn?